# How do I generate a file with suitable permissions using sprintf() & write()?

Tags: permissions, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


void main(){
    char tmp[12]={0x0};
    int i=13;
    sprintf(tmp,"%11d", i);
    int fd = open("transaction.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR);
    write(fd, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
}
```

I'm trying to write integers to a file.
because linux does not offer itoa function, I have to try to use **sprintf**.
but I can't read the result file.

The file created is owned by me but has permissions `------xr-x`. This means that my user can't read or write the file and my group has no access at all but strangely other users can read it.

[image: transaction.txt properties]

The file is readable if I run `sudo cat transaction.txt` which gives `13` as expected.

How can I generate a file with suitable permissions so that is is usable.

Comment: This works (except `fd=` needs to be `FILE* fd=`)

Comment: This may be better asked on Stack Overflow or Code Review.  You probably don't want to use sprintf or even a temporary variable.  A couple of quick suggestions for functions to consider:  fprintf(), fopen(), fclose().

Comment: @dv3500ea: `FILE*` is required by `fopen`, raw `open` return and `int`

Comment: @enzotib so *that's* why it was giving me a typecasting error. My C knowledge is lacking to say the least. So `fd=` needs to be `int fd=`.

Comment: I've diagnosed the problem although I don't know the solution. The file created is owned by me but has permissions `------xr-x`. This means that my user can't read or write the file and my group has no access at all but strangely other users can read it. The file is human readable if you run `sudo cat transaction.txt` which gives `         13` as expected. The real question here is how to fix the permissions of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the line

```
int fd;
```

and modify the open call as follows:

```
fd = open("transaction.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 00644);
```